# How to remove cells that end with a certain number of digits?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a long list is URLs that i need to create a file only containing a certain part of the URLs.

Imagine my cells in Excel is like this:

```
A1 = https://www.example.com/_the-t-rex-9781541514560 
A2 = https://www.example.com/_books-and-movies 
A3 = https://www.example.com/_paid-bills-1238979483298 
A4 = https://www.example.com/_nothing-important 
A5 = https://www.example.com/_snowball-1238979483298
```

And so on.

What I need is to remove all the cells that ends with a 13-digit number. As you can see from my example, three of those URLs ends with a 13-digit number, while two don't.
The two that don't is the one I want to end up with. Delete all the others.

Can anyone help me with this in excel?

Alternative, show only these URLs in Screaming Frog. If someone who knows sees this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a helper column:

```
=ISNUMBER(--RIGHT(A1,13))
```

Then filter on TRUE and delete the visible rows.

[image]